# Is it possible to display ARKit preview in Picture in Picture (PiP) mode?

Tags: swift, arkit, metal, avcapturesession, picture-in-picture

I know iOS has recently added Picture-in-Picture mode for video-play back and video calls. Is it possible to present camera preview from the phone camera through PiP? Even better, would be possible to display an ARKit preview in PiP mode?

Would really appreciate any input on this front! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: No, apparently Apple doesn't allow it.